# Archivos Temporales con C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Estoy recuperando un Archivo de tipo Word de la base de datos y le doy una ruta de mi disco C y me lo guarda en mi carpeta Temp, pero yo no quiero guardar dicho archivo solo quiero abrirlo, estoy leyendo un poco y creo que tendria que generar un temporal por ejemplo en esta direccion y despues borrar el temporal.

```
C:\Users\elsusuario\AppData\Local\Temp
```

pero como creo desde C# el temporal y que desde temporales se pueda abrir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si el archivo de Word esta en la base de datos y obtienes los bytes de dicho archivo puedes hacer esto:

```
string rutaCarpeta = "C:\Temp\";
string nombreArchivo = "ArchivoWord.docx";
string rutaArchivoFinal = rutaCarpeta + nombreArchivo;
byte[] bytesArchivo = // aqui recuperas los bytes del archivo dese la bd;

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(rutaArchivoFinal, bytesArchivo); // Creas el temporal
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(rutaArchivoFinal); // Con esto lo abres
```

y listo.

si quieres borrar el archivo temporal para ahorrar espacio puedes borrarlo con:

```
System.IO.File.Delete(rutaArchivoFinal);
```

pero tendrías que asegurarte de que el archivo no este siendo utilizado.

Answer (score 2):

si quieres borrarlo apenas el usuario deje de usarlo, entonces tienes que esperar que el usuario termine el proceso, puede usar esto.

```
string rutaarchivo = "temp.docx";
var proceso = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(rutaarchivo);
proceso.WaitForExit();
System.IO.File.Delete(rutaarchivo);
```

`proceso.WaitForExit();` espera que termine el proceso, pero hasta donde me acuerdo acepta un parametro en millisegundos como maximo para cerrarse.